# Blender STL/OBJ Export not working after boolean modifier (difference)

Tags: 3d-printing, obj, boolean-modifier, stl

I am working on a project in blender using the Sverchok-Nodes. After solidifying the structure I want to cut off the sides by using the boolean modifier (difference, exact).

The cutting is working, but whenever I want to export the structure as an obj or stl-file, the Mesh is getting "destroyed"/"messy"/"glitchy" and cannot be uploaded in Preform or Prusa-slicer properly.

I already tried just exporting the mesh without applying the modifier and it worked. I seems like something is happening during the cutting.

Could it be that the gyroid structure is too complex? (it is quite complex tbh)

Blender Version: 4.0

Here you can see a picture of the "destroyed" Mesh in the Slicer.

[!Destroyed Mesh Preform Slicer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18jCI.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18jCI.png)

Do you know what do to?